# How to Insert JSON Parsed data into MYSQL

Tags: javascript, mysql, json, node.js, parsing

Here I am trying to insert JSON Parsed Data into MYSQL Database.  I created Table in MYSQL with  3 columns - link,url,description.My Table name in MYSQL is  information.. My code does not working. I am unable to find the mistake.. Can anyone help me!! Here is my code

### dbStore.js

```
var express=require('express');
var mysql=require('mysql');
var config = require('./config.json');

var dbConnect = mysql.createConnection({
user     :  config.user,
password :  config.password,
database :  config.database
});

dbConnect.connect(function(err){
    if(err){
        console.log(err);
    }else{
        console.log("connection success");
    }
});

function insert() {
    var key = $("#search1").val();
    var htmlContent = "";
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "http://api.duckduckgo.com/?q=" + key + "&format=json&pretty=1",
        dataType: "jsonp",
        success: function (data, status, jqXHR) {
            alert("on success");
            if (data.RelatedTopics.length != "") {
                for (var i = 0; i < data.RelatedTopics.length; i++) {
                    var desc = data.RelatedTopics[i].Text;
                    var url  = data.RelatedTopics[i].Icon.URL;
                    var link = data.RelatedTopics[i].FirstURL;
                    var data={
                        link: link,
                        url: url,
                        description: desc
                    };
                    dbConnect.query('INSERT INTO information SET?',data,function(err,res){});
                    htmlContent += "";
                    $('#div1').html(htmlContent);
                }
            }
        },
        error: "error"
    });
};
```

Table name is information(columns- link,url,description) .From my html page on-click event I called the insert() function in dbStore.js that will parse json data from api and insert data in table.  Thank you in advance.

Comment: Does it every get to the alert() statement? Also, htmlContent variable never changes (bringing it up in case you are watching it)

Answer (score 1):

It looks like that isn't valid SQL.

Should be something like

```
INSERT INTO information (`link`, `url`, `description`) VALUES(?,?,?)
```

EDIT: It also looks like htmlContent never changes, so you may want to adjust that according to your needs.

EDIT2: You have your datatype set to jsonp. That should be JSON based on your DuckDuckGo API call.
JsonP is JSON that is generally padded with javascript and loaded through a script tag. This requires special preparation on the server. DuckDuckGo is returning generic JSON for you.

Comment: See Edit2 for another solution

Comment: Thankyou for response, I solved it. sorry for delay.